# How do I access a variable which contains a dot?

Tags: javascript

Following is my script

```
var err=activityLocal.message;
var text="";
var i;
    for (i = 0; i < err.length; i++) {
            text+= err[i].message +";";
}
document.write(text);
```

Here the value of `activityLocal.message` as shown below:

```
[{
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'manaed_server_4'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}, {
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'managed_server_3'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}];
```

But the output is `undefined`, seems like JS engine gets confused with the dot in `activityLocal.message` variable. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: do you have really a json? a string? or just an array?

Comment: activityLocal is an array , access message using activityLocal[index].message

Comment: It looks like you are putting your array in activityLocal.message. you should call you first element message by activityLocal.message[0].message. or adjust as per your code

Comment: what is the value of variable `text` when you using single step debug after running `text+= err[i].message +";";` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code their is problem with variable name it should not contain dot it is illegal .

```
var activityLocal_message = [{
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'manaed_server_4'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}, {
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'managed_server_3'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}];

var err=activityLocal_message;
var text="";
var i;
    for (i = 0; i < err.length; i++) {
            text+= err[i].message +";";
            //console.log(err[i].message);
}
console.log(text);
```

or else if you really want to use with dot operator try this

You can't use variables in dot notation (short of using eval, which you don't want to do). With dot notation the property name is essentially a constant.

```
myObj.propName
// is equivalent to
myObj["propName"]
```

Comment: why to modify the original variable activityLocal.message to activityLocal_message, it might be not possible to do in original code.

Comment: In the question he clearly mentioned about dot in his variable

Comment: May be he can access that property by activityLocal["message"] i think

Comment: Try to answer questions without modifying original source.

Comment: No changing the variable name is not possible, as I'm not declaring it in my java script it's a variable defined somewhere else in service now and I'm supposed to use it in java script  and using `activityLocal["message"]` gives me same output i.e. `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `map` function to loop through all messages in the `activityLocal.message` which will return array of `strings` and the join them using array `join` function like this:

```js
var err= [{
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'manaed_server_4'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}, {
  "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'managed_server_3'.",
  "severity": "FAILURE"
}];

var text= err.map(function(e) {
  return e.message;
}).join(";");

alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is able loop the values but the problem might be setting it in the html. below is the code and you can also check in the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ltMVW0mnnwTkTZoeMAxT?p=preview)

```
// Code goes here

var activityLocal = {};
activityLocal.message = [
  {
    message:
      "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'manaed_server_4'.",
    severity: 'FAILURE',
  },
  {
    message:
      "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'managed_server_3'.",
    severity: 'FAILURE',
  },
];
var err = activityLocal.message;
var text = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < err.length; i++) {
  text += err[i].message + ';';
  //alert(text);
}
document.getElementById('showtext').innerHTML = 'tttt' + text;
```

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score -4):

If you mean that you want to use the dot as the variable name, it is simply not possible.

If you want to use it as an object variable, it is accessible via the `object.variableName`. E. g. assume your object is named `myObj` and you variable assigned to that object is called `myVar` you can access it with this call: `myObj.myVar`. Or you can also iterate over the object using the for (or foreach in modern JavaScript runtime environments) loop.